# XSLT handling text with tag in between

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have the following XML: `<a>Text with <b>stuff</b> here</a>`

With my code:

```
<xsl:template match="*[local-name() = 'a'][namespace-uri()=namespace-uri(.)]">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(text()) "/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[local-name() = 'b'][namespace-uri()=namespace-uri(.)]">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(text())"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

I only get the result:

> Text with stuff

What I want is:

> Text with stuff here.

So how do I handle the remaining text after the `<b/>` element?

Comment: It would be helpful to see more of your stylesheet. When I only apply those templates, I get different output. It produces `Text with Text with stuff stuff here`

Answer (score 1):

Why is this so complicated? If this is really your XML input:

```
<a>Text with <b>stuff</b> here</a>
```

then the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="a" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return the requested* result:

```
Text with stuff here
```

--
(*) except for the period at the end, which is not present in the input.